# Rational functions of order $3$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, involutions

Let $p$ be a prime, let $\mathbb K$ a field with $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb K)=p$ and $\mathbb{K}(x)$ be the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{K}[x]$, i.e. $$\mathbb{K}(x)=\left\{\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}:g,h \in\mathbb{K}[x], h\neq 0\right\}.$$

My central question is this:

> How to characterize elements of order 3 in $\mathbb{K}(x)$, that is, rational functions $f\in \mathbb{K}(x)$ such that $f^3(x):=f\circ f\circ f(x)=x$? Are there explicit formulas for such $f$ and/or conditions that (the coefficients of) $f$ must satisfy?

Also, any input on elements of finite order $n> 3$ would be greatly appreciated!

---

What I found out so far: In the case of linear fractional transformations, we can write $$f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{x+d}, \qquad a,b,d\in \mathbb{K},$$ and from the condition that $f^3(x)=x$ we can explicitly derive $$b=-a^2-ad-d^2,$$ thus giving us a very clear picture of how these elements look like. Unfortunately, my approach (essentially consisting of symbolic calculations in Sage) becomes impractical for $\mathrm{deg}(g), \mathrm{deg}(h)>1$.

Also there is [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2298535?seq=1?seq=1) by E. F. Allen that characterizes linear fractional transformations of *any* order, but it only applies to polynomials with real coefficients.

Comment: I thought that by definition an involution has order two.

Comment: It is known that for every field $K$, the only $f\in  K(t)$ that are invertible under composition are homographies $(at+b)/(ct+d)$ (which form the group $\mathrm{PGL}_2(K)$. So the whole picture reduces to classifying torsion elements (here, of order $3$) in this group. The latter follows from a discussion: char 3 vs char $\neq 3$, and whether $t^2+t+1$ is irreducible in $K[t]$.

Comment: Since $\deg(f^n)=\deg(f)^n$, the assumption that $f^n(x)=x$ and $n\ge2$ implies that $\deg(f)=1$. For linear maps, you're asking for the elements if finite order in $\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb K)$, which for order prime to $p$, can be analyzed by looking at the eigenvalues. And of course there are maps such as $f(x)=x+a$ that has order $p$.

Comment: Somewhat related: For $p=k^2+k+1$ you can multiply with $k$ as involution of order $3$ not just of $x$ but of any element in the field of fractions.

Comment: @DaveBenson You're right, in standard textbooks involutions are of the second order, so maybe the terminology isn't 100% accurate here.

Comment: @YCor Thank you for your answer! I was unaware of the group $\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb K)$ and will take a look into this.

Comment: @JoeSilverman Thank you for your answer! Is there a similar argument for other types of functions (e.g. $n$-th roots)? For instance $-\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$ is an involution of order 2.

Comment: @Mersn Calling elements of order $3$ involutions is 100% inaccurate :-) By the way, your elements in $R$ are rational functions, you shouldn't call them polynomials.

Comment: Probably a stupid comment but: If $p \neq 0$ then $\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}=x$ for all $x$ if and only if $X^p-X$ divides $g(X)-Xh(X)$.... Now, calculate "explicitely"  $f \circ f \circ f$ for $f= \frac{\sum a_n X^n}{\sum b_m X^m}$ and apply the above criteria.

Comment: Also: since each function $f: \mathbb K \to \mathbb  K$ is a polynomial function, the problem boils down to fist finding all functions on $K$ satisfying these conditions (hence partitioning $\mathbb K$ into sets of 1 or 3 elements) and then finding all rational polynomials which are equal to a certain function. Lagrange interpolation gives you one, and then should be an easy exercise to find all.

Comment: @NickS: This is the wrong way of thinking about this problem. Rational functions are not honest functions $f\colon \mathbb{K}\to \mathbb{K}$ (for example their denominators can have roots, so they are not defined for certain values of $x$); they are just elements of the ring $\mathbb{K}(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

Since you ask, there has been much research on the analogous question of elements of finite order in the [Nottingham group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nottingham_group), which is the group of power series under composition:
$$ N(\mathbb K) = \left\{ x + \sum_{n\ge2} c_nx : c_n\in \mathbb K\right\}. $$
especially for $\mathbb K$ a finite field. Your example $-\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$ is almost of this form, it's expansion starts $ix+\text{h.o.t.}$ See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/425844), which is related to what you're asking about, and my answer to that question gives some references that discuss elements of finite order in the Nottingham group.

Comment: I understand this question is asking about positive characteristic, but is it not true that if $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$ then the only rational functions of finite order are Möbius transformations?

Comment: @SamHopkins This was pointed out by Joe Silverman in his comment for the OP's question, no matter what the field $\mathbb K$ ist.

Comment: Okay, I see. Then I'm confused what the OP's question actually is. Doesn't that answer it?